# Converting readAsBinaryString to Data:URI

Tags: javascript

I have a `binaryString` variable as `readAsBinaryString`. How can I convert it to data:uri?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {
    var binaryString = reader.result;
    console.log(binaryString);
    console.log(window.btoa(binaryString));//does not contain mime-type at the beginning
}
var file=document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files[0];
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

I need to operate over directly `binaryString`. I am sending the `binaryString` to another Javascript application. So in that context I only have `binaryString` value. The code above is just an example. Please do not recommend `URL.createObjectURL` or `FileRader.readAsDataURL`.

I need to operate over `binaryString` directly and convert it `data:uri`.

Comment: Have you tried to simply prepend the required text? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: Thanks it is a solution but the other side does not need to know the mimetype. If possible I need to retrieve the mimetype from the binaryString too.